# Docker container can't access Basler GigE vision camera

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, ethernet, basler

We use docker container for python project. We create all files and we need to connect basler camera via GigE vision protocol. We grab frames with pylon viewer very well. What can we do for access basler cam?

we applied this code snipped;

```
docker network create -d ipvlan --subnet=192.168.3.0/24 --ip-range=192.168.3.0/24 -o ipvlan_mode=l2 -o parent=enp11s0f1 camvlan

docker run -ti --network=camvlan pylonimage
```

But did not access camera. What can we do for access basler cam?

Note: We use docker for desktop in windows and our docker container is including Ubuntu.

Comment: What specific problems are you having?  With the default networking setup a container should be able to access devices on the host's network fine, either by IP address or fully-qualified DNS name; if you remove the `docker run --network` option, does it work?

Comment: Actually I removed --network arguments and access the camera. But I can't get frame for the my docker image. When I searched reasons, I faced bandwidth problem and some users had set bridge structure (macvlan,ipvlan, etc.). So I set bridge structure and I can't access any device.

Comment: Hi @erenpostaci
could it be a MTU setting mismatch of the docker bridge at the host interface configuration? I found a post about docker and MTU here:
https://mlohr.com/docker-mtu/